# HTML5's File API - How to know what's being dragged on?

Tags: file, html, upload

I've just started working with HTML5's File API. I've been able to mimick imgur's behavior: when a file is being dragged into the document, a big overlay appears with a message to drop to start uploading.

However, I just noticed something: **if you drag any element in the page (text, images), the overlay shows up**. You can try it on [imgur](http://imgur.com/), it's the same thing that happens with my code.

Altough when releasing, nothing actually happens because the script will check if there are files to upload. My question is, **how to know beforehand what's being dragged in the document?** At first I thought it was not possible since imgur and all the [demos](http://robertnyman.com/html5/fileapi-upload/fileapi-upload.html) [out](http://html5demos.com/file-api) there have the same issue.

To my surprise, Gmail can detect whether it's a file or just something else that's being dragged on, but it would be fairly impossible to trackback the snippet.

(I can provide code if you want, however it's pretty simple: the events `dragenter`, `dragover` and `drop` are added to the `document` element and everything is handled as in the demos)

Thanks.

### Update

robertc's answer is correct, that seems to be the way to check for Firefox. By trial and error, I've found a way to check with Chrome:

```
event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.types.indexOf('Files')
```

It will return `-1` if there are no files. So you can now do something like:

```
try {
    if(event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.types.indexOf('Files') == -1){
        return false;
    }
} catch(E){}

try {
    if(!event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.types.contains("application/x-moz-file")){
        return false;
    }
} catch(E){}
```

However I don't think that's the best way to test it, but adding both conditionals in the `try` will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to test the drag type in the `dragover`/`dragenter` event.  In Firefox a file will have type `application/x-moz-file` so you can do [some variation of this](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Recommended_Drag_Types#Dragging_Files):

```
function checkDrag(event) {
    return event.dataTransfer.types.contains("application/x-moz-file");
}
```

I'm not sure what the equivalent types are for other browsers.

Comment: You're right! Thanks. I've updated my question to make it cross-browser (at least adding support for Chrome).

Comment: @metrobalderas Good find on the WebKit front, you might be able to clean up your code with something like [Prototype's Try.these](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/try-these)

Comment: @metrobalderas that doesn't mean you can't steal good bits of code from other frameworks ;) I'm not sure what the dependencies are like for `Try.these` though, it may be too much work.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to ignore dragged URLs, text, etc (non-files) in my handleDrop(event):

```
if(typeof event.dataTransfer.files == "undefined" || 
     event.dataTransfer.files.length == 0)
        return;
```

but it doesn't catch folders.